# Publishing one generic fail event and attaching data to it or publish multiple specific fail event

Tags: domain-driven-design, masstransit, domain-events

So we have a scenario where we are creating credit cards. We have `CreateCardConsumer` that internally implements a strategy that decides which credit card provider API will be used (currently, we have two, let's call them, Provider1 and Provider2).

In case that credit card creation fails, we have the `FailedToCreateCard` event that gets published in `CreateCardConsumer`:

```
public class CreateCardConsumer : IConsumer<CreateCard>
{
   public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<CreateVirtualCard> context)
   {
      try
      {
        // Decide which provider to use
      }
      catch (Provider1Exception e)
      {
      }
      catch (Provider2Exception e)
      {
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        await context.Publish<FailedToCreateCard>(new(context.Message.CardId));
      }
   }
}
```

The issue with this is that when card creation fails, we must inform multiple systems that creation failed (and there, we use the `FailedToCreateCard` event). We also need to send a notification to our support with error details (which are a different data structure for both providers).

It feels fishy to extend `FailedToCreateCard` event with the error data for both providers and listen in the consumer that sends an email to the support (in the future there can be more than 2 providers), but it also feels fishy that we do something like

```
catch (Provider1Exception e)
{
  await context.Publish<FailedToCreateProvider1Card>(new(context.Message.CardId, e));
  await context.Publish<FailedToCreateCard>(new(context.Message.CardId));
}
catch (Provider2Exception e)
{
  await context.Publish<FailedToCreateProvider2Card>(new(context.Message.CardId, e));
  await context.Publish<FailedToCreateCard>(new(context.Message.CardId));
}
```

And the third solution that comes to mind is that we publish `FailedToCreateProvider1Card` and `FailedToCreateProvider2Card` from within the service that makes an API call and publish `FailedToCreateCard` in the consumer.

Does any one of these solution makes sense or there is a fourth one that is a common practice in this scenario?

Comment: Is it the same data just provided to different recepients that expect different data structures or is it really also different data of interest published to the different providers?

Comment: Different data, completely.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a broker like RabbitMQ, MassTransit supports polymorphic messaging. You can read more [in the documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/topology/rabbitmq.html#broker-topology), but by having two interfaces implemented by a single class (which would be published), you can produce a single *event* that would be routed via either message type.

Comment: We are using SNS ana SQS and it doesn't support polymorphic messaging. I've tried that first.